# Geometry with circle and triangle.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Any other solutions(advice) are welcome.
What I am asking is this because I am studying mathematics through feedback process of my solution and learning new solutions.
Please, release Hold on.

When will the hold be resolved? I want to see your new solutions(or advices).

$\overline{AE}$ is a diameter.
and $\overline{AB}=1,\;\;\; \overline{AC}=2$
and  $\overline{BD}:\overline{CD}=3:2$

Find the area of $\triangle ABC$ .

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: the question is asking for alternative solutions to your problem? If you're trying to share your solution by [answering your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) there is an option to do so when asking a question.

Comment: @user574848 Yes, it's good option. Thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here is a completely different soluiton based on trigonometry.

From triangle $ABD$:

$$\frac{3x}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{l}{\sin(90^\circ-\beta)}\tag{1}$$

From triangle $ADC$:

$$\frac{2x}{\sin\beta}=\frac{l}{\sin(90^\circ-\alpha)}\tag{2}$$

From triangle $ABC$:

$$\frac{1}{\sin(90^\circ-\alpha)}=\frac{2}{\sin(90^\circ-\beta)}\tag{3}$$

Rewrite (1),(2)(3):

$$\frac{3x}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{l}{\cos\beta}\tag{4}$$

$$\frac{2x}{\sin\beta}=\frac{l}{\cos\alpha}\tag{5}$$

$$\cos\beta=2\cos\alpha\tag{6}$$

We don't care about $l$, just divide (4) by (5) to eliminate it:

$$\frac{3\sin\beta}{2\sin\alpha}=\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}$$

$$3\sin\beta\cos\beta=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\tag{7}$$

Now you have (6) and (7), two equations with two unknown angles. Divide (7) by (6) and you get:

$$3\sin\beta=\sin\alpha\tag{8}$$

Now divide (6) by 2, square and add to (8) squared to eliminate $\alpha$:

$$9\sin^2\beta+\frac14\cos^2\beta=1$$

$$36\sin^2\beta+cos^2\beta=4$$

$$35\sin^2\beta=3$$

The rest is straightforward:

$$\sin\beta=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{35}}, \ \ \cos\beta=\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{35}}$$

From (8):

$$\sin\alpha=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{35}}, \ \ \cos\alpha=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{35}}$$

Now:

$$S=\frac12 AB\cdot h=\frac12 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin(\alpha+\beta)$$

$$S=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta=\frac{2\sqrt{6}}{5}$$

Comment: Yes, good idea. In fact, (8)$\;3sin\;\beta=sin\;\alpha\;$ $\Rightarrow$$\;\; 3\times \frac{\overline{EC}}{\overline{AE}}=\frac{\overline{EB}}{\overline{AE}} $$\;\;\Rightarrow \;3\overline{EC}=\overline{EB}$ Thank you very much.